# How to check if multiple string variables are empty?

Tags: python, string

I have multiple variables that start out empty. I want to check if all of them are still empty. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Something like this:

```
a = ''
b= ''
c = ''

if not (a,b,c):
    print("All Empty")
```

Comment: not any((a,b,c)) or all(not i for i in (a, b, c))

Comment: `if not any((a,b,c))`

Comment: if not (a or b or c)

Comment: gotcha, I knew there was an easy way but couldn't find it. Much better than using len()>0

Answer (score 3):

More readable but a bit more verbose:

```
if a == b == c == '':
```

Somewhat more clever and shorter:

```
if not any((a, b, c)):
```

Comment: `'' == a == b == c` could be more efficient (in case the strings are large and equal).

Comment: `len` is almost certainly a constant-time operation, as strings are immutable and their length cannot change once created. The benefit of ending early if `a` is not empty would be minimal.

Comment: @chepner Hmm, nobody here is talking about `len`. What are you referring to?

Comment: len is actually how i did it initially:

if len(a + b + c) == 0:

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode The string length is irrelevant to how long `'' == a` will take. The only thing putting `''` first in the chain would help is avoiding two extra comparisons if `a == b == c` but if they are all non-empty.

Comment: `len(a +  b + c)` *is* a problem if the strings are large, because you'll potentially spend O(n) time creating `a + b + c` before `len` determines the length of the resulting string.

Comment: @chepner Well those `a == b == c` are exactly what I'm talking about. [Demo where mine is ~5000 times faster](https://tio.run/##TVBbasMwEPzXKYZAkGREsQmYEvBJQiiyI7f60ANJ@cjdcoZeydXaber9WK1GM8Os4qN8BX96j2lZ5hQcinXGFlgXQypIJhpdGMum3CMGcM6Zr2fXomnQM03YG0cDz8bdPO1m0rAp3Eyu4IWh1sHOqNIBI7WJGudnRJ0zDupF8aFA@4cQWmFUmKTcODsK5yTeef27XBmbQ8IHrEfS/tOIkzyvQoIpEL2swTaYitavMZ31YttdEEFh/QAFf3ejSUPXtq2UL1FM1v8Reb0f@xu@n5njCLEaNuhM/yvYyHJZfgA). You're calling that "minimal"? I can make the factor even larger with longer strings. How large do I need to make it for it to not be "minimal" anymore?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ''
b = ''
c = ''

if not all([a, b, c]):
    print("All Empty")
```

Comment: The generator expression is not needed. `[a,b,c]` itself is a perfectly fine argument to `any`.